# How can I use a function from one Javascript file in another?

Tags: javascript

I have the following Javascript file, one.js:

```
function doSomething() {
    console.log("doing stuff");
}
```

I have another Javascript file, two.js, in which I want to call `doSomething()`:

```
doSomething();
```

How can I achieve this? Note this code is for a browser extension so I cannot use html.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript import function syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157936/javascript-import-function-syntax)

Answer (score 2):

You have to `import` the function from `one.js` as below :
`import doSomething from "one.js";`

Then assign it to some variable of current object and use it.
`this.doSomething = doSomething();`

Answer (score 0):

you can use scripts as background and content script in extensions code, you can do something like that,

```
 "background": {
 "scripts": [ "js/sharedFunctions.js", "js/mainBackground.js" ]
 },
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["*://*/*"],
    "js": ["js/sharedFunctions.js", "js/mainContentScript.js"]
  }
]
```

then functions of first file can be used in second as per order

Comment: At the end of question , it is mentioned ,"Note this code is for a browser extension so I cannot use html."

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake